# How to call template file to check mail?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having problem to call template pankaj.html after sending mail. I have search through google but not found better solution to solve my issue.

```
path: /app/locale/en_US/template/email/pankaj.html
```

& i am calling template file in config.xml of module under global tag.

```
 <template>
            <email>
                <inquiry  module="inquiry">
                    <label>pankaj</label>
                    <file>pankaj.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </inquiry>
            </email>
   </template>
```

**Controller code:**

```
 public function sendemailAction()
        {
            echo "abc";
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); 

            $adminUserModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
            $admin = $adminUserModel->getCollection()->load();

            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('inquiry');


            $senderName = $admin->getFirstItem()->getFirstname();
            $senderEmail = $admin->getFirstItem()->getEmail();  
        $sender = array('name' => $senderName,
            'email' => $senderEmail);


        $recepientEmail = array();
        $recepientName =array();

        /*$customer_name = $senderName = $customer->getFirstname().' '.$customer->getLastname();*/
        $recepientEmail = $data['email'];

        $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        $vars = array('product_name' => $data['productname'],
            'sku' => $data['sku'],
            'qty' => $data['qty'],
            'customprice' => $data['customprice']
            );

        $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

        // Send Transactional Email

        try {


            Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->sendTransactional($emailTemplate, $sender, $recepientEmail, $vars, $store);


            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);   


            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('email send');

        }        
        catch(Exception $ex) {

            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error.');

        }
        $this->_redirect('');
    }
```

To check **pankaj.html** file, i have print `$text` in **template.php** file.
  `echo "<pre>"; print_r($text); die;`

**path: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/template.php**

How to solve this issue, Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to solve issue

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('inquiry');
```

I suggest you to following magento default contact us email

Comment: i have replace loadDefault('pankaj') to loadDefault('inquiry') but still i am having problem to call pankaj.html

Comment: follow Magento Contact module it's best practice